# R, Python, rpy2: "Error: cannot allocate vector of size xxx Mb"

Tags: python, r, memory, rpy2

I work on Python 3.7 with R 3.5.1.
When I call my function from the R script from Python it works in principle, however in the end it crashes with output:

> rpy2.rinterface.RRuntimeError: Error: cannot allocate vector of size 1006.0 Mb

I have 16GB of RAM and I inspected during the long processing the fluctuations of memory usage which maxed at less than 5GB.

To make things even more certain of what's going on I traced memory usage with

```
gc() 
gcinfo(TRUE)
```

which dumps garbage and tracks when R does so too by itself.

Additionally, in R I get the following, indicating 16k MB which is all my default RAM:

```
> memory.limit()
[1] 16244
```

Finally, when I run the R script straight from R it works fine and no memory issues are encountered.

Is it a formidable bug of rpy2 or something else that could be managed right now? If anyone has any suggestions they are most welcome, I will try.

OS: Windows 10, 64bit

Comment: rpy2 isn't "aware" of the size of your R workspace when running a script. You may want to add manual garbage collection if you're running something in a loop or list. You can do this in your R script using `gc()` between iterations.

Comment: Discussed here: http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.1/html/performances.html

Comment: I do not get what you say really. I did use gc(). I explicitly say so above. It is not needed really, R takes care for that, but I used it just to be on the safe side.

Just also to show what I am saying, I still got the output from R gc() from the Python side output:

Comment: Garbage collection 20 = 13+2+5 (level 2) ... 
65.3 Mbytes of cons cells used (53%)
13.8 Mbytes of vectors used (13%)
... MANY MORE LIKE THE ABOVE
1145.7 Mbytes of vectors used (44%)
Garbage collection 38 = 15+3+20 (level 2) ... 
65.5 Mbytes of cons cells used (53%)
1145.7 Mbytes of vectors used (37%)
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 1006.0 Mb
...MANY MORE LIKE THE ABOVE
Garbage collection 41 = 15+3+23 (level 2) ... 
65.5 Mbytes of cons cells used (53%)
13.9 Mbytes of vectors used (2%)

Comment: I apologize, but without seeing more of your code it's really challenging to diagnose the problem. I've seen problems like this before with parallel processes but I think your error message is very clear. You are using too much memory. There are only a few recommendations possible: profile your code, write memory usage to a file so you can debug where the error occurs or use a machine with more RAM.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, but still you seem to avoid reading my text carefully. I do not need more RAM for sure. I monitored it. The issue is the memory usage on the Python side most probably, a matter difficult to handle due to inexperience and lack of time (unless straightforward suggestions are made)

Comment: I am reading carefully. Using gc() once, may not be enough - frequently it's required in every iteration (share your code!). Similarly, just because you're monitoring RAM does not mean you will visually see the point of failure (profile your code!).

Answer (score 1):

From this [thread](https://bitbucket.org/rpy2/rpy2/issues/421/pandas2ripy2ri-use-way-too-much-ram) :

> This seems to be caused by hard-to-reconcile differences between...R vectors and Python arrays.

I can suggest doing the following as a workaround:

- communicate the vector data via a mutual accessible place for both R and Python (e.g. database, csv file in a common folder etc.)
- open a ticket on the rpy2 page (or continue the thread linked)
- break up your data (if possible) to the maximum size the you can transfer via rpy2 and loop over it until you cover your whole data set (maybe a small alteration on both sides can achieve this - depending on your code)
- consider a type of conversion that is offered in the thread, such as:

  `from rpy2.robjects import conversion 
  df_R = conversion.converter.py2ri(df_pandas)`

*Moderator note: this could be a comment, but I am unable to post comments*